# Display turns off too soon

Tags: display, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

In Xfce power manager settings I have set 6 minutes timeout for turning display off (and never for sleep). However, display turns off sooner and
`xset q` displays (among other things):

> DPMS (Energy Star): 
>   Standby: 120    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
>   DPMS is Enabled

If I change the setting to say 7 minutes in Xfce power manager, the output is

> DPMS (Energy Star):
>     Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 420
>     DPMS is Enabled

But I want the Xfce setting to be effective from start. What sets the DPMS timeout value to different from Xfce setting? Xcreensaver is not installed.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with Xfce desktop

Workaround:

Add the following command in Application Autostart tab of Session and Startup dialog:

```
/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5 && xset dpms 0 $((60*$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-sleep))) $((60*$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-off)))'
```

(This is for AC mode. You may have to adjust the argument for `sleep` larger.)

Answer (score 1):

On startup mine has `xset q` settings that don't match xfce's power manager settings either, like 7200 standby & 14400 off, but it still seems to react to the xfce settings anyway. So your case sounds more like a bug, but there's a workaround below.

Changing them in xfce's power manager changes the xset settings.

I'm not sure what to do to get the settings to match right on boot, they appear to be stored in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml` but editing that file doesn't change the power manager or xset settings... though maybe a logout/login is required.

The `xfce4-settings-editor` program does change the settings in the xml file and power manager, while changing the power manager settings doesn't change the xml file (at least not right away).

---

## Use `xfconf-query`

To change the settings upon logging in (perhaps with a file in ~/.config/autostart). To set the "switch off after" / `/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-off` to say 15 minutes run this:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-off -s 15
```

To query the current setting, omit the `-s`:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-off
```

Comment: I put the `xfconf-query` command to Application Autostart, but it did not help. The Standby time is still 120 and the rest timers are 0 after login.

Comment: If you run the `xfconf-query ... -s N` command in a terminal after being logged in for a while, does it change `xset`'s output then? If it works then might have to add a `sleep 60` before the command in autostart, I've noticed it takes a while for the desktop to get everything up & running (ex. an early `conky` won't be visible, but wait a while first and everything's ok)

Comment: My case is not more bug than your case: It reacts to xfce4 settings done during session.

Comment: One thing that prevent `xfconf-query -s` from working is that the value must be different than the stored value. Othervise DPMS settings will not be touched.

Comment: I added a workaround in the question.

Comment: Didn't think to try testing by setting the same time at first, was always trying different times so I could tell if it changed (after the 1st time)